# Using Luacom to change cell borders in excel

Tags: vba, excel, lua, luacom

I have a range of cells in excel and i need to ensure that all borders are shown.

So far i have:

```
oExcel = luacom.GetObject("Excel.Application");
Book = oExcel.Workbooks:Open(_DesktopFolder .. "\\document.xlsx");
Sheet = Book.WorkSheets(1);

RangeRef = "A3:E56"
local BorderList = Sheet:Range(RangeRef)

BorderList:Select();
```

I know the next part is something like this:

```
BorderList.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle(xlContinuous)
```

but i can't seem to get it to work. I get an error back saying "Error: " which is really helpful :P

Anyone got any info on this?
Thanks